# Display literal text in HTML

Tags: c#, html, escaping, character

I need to display some literal text in my HTML page (it's automatically generated by an application. I wrote in C#.)

```
<TR>
    <TD VALIGN="center" ALIGN="center"><B>398</B></TD>
    <TD VALIGN="center">Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<B>' an image.jpg</B></TD>         
    <TD><IMG SRC="Images/' an image.jpg"ALT=' an image.jpg></TD>
</TR>
```

The " **'** " character causes the problem, because it's a HTML escape character. (There are also other escape characters used in file names.) I can't change the file names. So how can I display the literal text in my HTML page?

Comment: It's a Windows Form Application creating a html file as result.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
&#39;
```

instead.

Here is reference to HTML Entities and Codings (http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/entities.html)

Comment: It's not only the apex '. There are also other escape characters used in the file names.

Comment: That's why he/she/it posted a link to a more complete list for your perusal.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: in case of Windows Forms, you can use:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(yourString);
```

It is necessary to add a reference to `System.Web.dll` in your project. Remember that in HTML the attributes should be enclosed with the quote char " and not with apex, `'`.

---

You can simply use the

```
HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode
```

method; moreover, the `'` is not the problem, maybe it can be the quote, `"`, or `<` and `>` characters.

The following example encodes a string for transmission by HTTP. It encodes the string named TestString, which contains the text `"This is a <Test String>."`, and copies it into the string named EncodedString as `"This is a &lt;Test String&gt;."`.

C#:

```
String TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
String EncodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```

Comment: I created a Windows Form Application and used; SecurityElement.Escape(myString) to create an encoded string. Im my html file the name is now: &apos; an image.jpg instead of  ' an image.jpg

Comment: if your problem is only the apex ' then you can leave in html: <a href="foo/' foo">

Comment: I encoded the string and this is the (visible) result in my html page; `&apos; an image.jpg` `file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/...../Images/&apos; an image.jpg` and this is my html source: `<TR> <TD VALIGN="center">Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<B>&apos; an image.jpg</B></TD> <TD><IMG SRC="Images/&apos; an image.jpg"ALT=&apos; an image.jpg></TD></TR>` What's going wrong ?

Comment: B.T.W `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` doesn't encode the " ' ", `SecurityElement.Escape` does.

Comment: shame, shame. Fixed. Missed the qoutes for the attribute `ALT=` The correct format without any encoding; `<TR> <TD VALIGN="center">Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<B>' an image.jpg</B></TD> <TD><IMG SRC="Images/' an image.jpg"ALT="' an image.jpg"></TD></TR>

Comment: i've tell you. Accept the answer if it is useful for you.